# Swaping elements in 3d numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.4

Given a 3d numpy array how do I swap the first and the last element of each 'pixel'

For example:

```
a = [[[15  3 61]
    [56 27 22]
    [48 32 29]
    [38 21 50]
    [28 54 37]]

    [[47 27 35]
    [52 34 12]
    [18 56 48]
    [ 8 34  1]
    [37 27 38]]]
```

I want the array to be:

```
a = [[[61  3 15]
    [22 27 56]
    [29 32 48]
    [50 21 38]
    [37 54 28]]
```

and so on

Is there a way to do it without using loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the array along the third axis by `a[..., ::-1]`:

```
a = np.array([[[15,  3, 61],
    [56, 27, 22],
    [48, 32, 29],
    [38, 21, 50],
    [28, 54, 37]],
    [[47, 27, 35],
    [52, 34, 12],
    [18, 56, 48],
    [ 8, 34,  1],
    [37, 27, 38]]])

a[..., ::-1]
#array([[[61,  3, 15],
#        [22, 27, 56],
#        [29, 32, 48],
#        [50, 21, 38],
#        [37, 54, 28]],

#       [[35, 27, 47],
#        [12, 34, 52],
#        [48, 56, 18],
#        [ 1, 34,  8],
#        [38, 27, 37]]])
```